Do I need to install drivers for my graphic card in ubuntu?
I'm new to ubuntu and installed it (22.04) a few days ago on a new computer. (then updated to 22.04.4)
While installation, I didn't select "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats" option
My graphics card is AMD Rx 6600xt , for gaming usage do I need to install any drivers for it, or ubuntu has installed them already?
I searched the web but almost didn't understand anything.
Thanks for your answers

I recommend one driver for one hardware device. Do not install multiple drivers, that is, 12 drivers for one AMD Rx 6600xt is a bad idea.

Ubuntu offers a GUI based tool to help you configure your sources and drivers. To use it, you can open the “additional drivers” GUI:

This will open the Software & Updates GUI where you can add third-party software, and as well you can see if there are any drivers shown that are recommended (on the screenshot it says "getestet"):

If you would rather not use a graphical tool, you can as well open the terminal and run sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, though this option is depricated. Anyway, it worked in my case. Since I have an Nvidia graphics card, I'm not quite sure about AMD.
Further commands you can use to check for your video card and driver are:

sudo lshw -c video
glxinfo -B


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for your info.
But when I open the additional drivers app, it shows me:
** "No additional drivers available" **
But I haven't installed drivers manually before. And now, that confuses me.
Do I have to do anything, or installing games will be OK?

If you are not facing any issues, you are fine. Maybe Ubuntu just provides all the needed drivers out of the box. So I'd suggest just trying to run some games.
